# HTTP Request List<dynamic> is not a subtype of Map<String,dynamic>

Tags: flutter, http, dart, httprequest

I tried to do a http request on flutter, but at the request there is the message List is not a subtype of Map<String,dynamic> but when I change the code to a get a List there is the error Map<String,dynamic> is not a subtype of List.
I have absolutly no idea what to do at this point.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.https('***'),
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
          "key ***"
    },
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception(
        'Failed to load data\n Response: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
  }
}
class Album {
  final String ascii;
  final String deviceId;
  final String raw;
  final String time;
  Album({this.ascii, this.deviceId, this.raw, this.time});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      ascii: json['ASCII'],
      deviceId: json['device_id'],
      raw: json['raw'],
      time: json['time'],
    );}}
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Album> futureAlbum;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.ascii);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },),),),);}}
```

Comment: Its happen if you try to return json object, but it is return json array

Comment: basically it means the data which you are receiving after hitting a webservice is in form of List but inside data class which you have used is of type Map